# Link to use when iOS app/game posts to Facebook or Twitter

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, twitter, app-store

I just developed a new game (called Ktalu: Planet of Terror) in iOS using COCOS2D. The game itself is done but I have to finalize a couple of things, one being the following. This game allows users to post their high scores on Facebook and/or Twitter, and everything works fine right now. The Facebook post shows up as expected and some of the text is linked to a URL of my choice. My question is what link should I use here? I can link to the website of the game (ktalu.com) but it is probably a better idea to link directly to the game in the App Store. This way, anyone who sees a post on Facebook when reading on an iPhone can click the link and be taken directly to App Store. But I am confused as to how to do this. The only link I have now is a link to the game in iTunes Connect. Remember, this game is not published yet. How can I get an App Store link for this game to put into Facebook posts and Tweets if the game is not yet in the App Store? And what exactly does this link look like? Is it http, https, or something else? And what happens if someone reads the post on a laptop or desktop and clicks that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "View in App Store" link (Manage Apps, ) is exactly what you want. That URL will work once an app goes live, even if copied pre-launch because it doesn't change. When followed on a non-iOS computer, this link goes to the online store. When followed on iOS, this link goes to the App Store.

- Protip: Use the URL scheme "itms://" instead of "http://" to link directly to your app in iTunes on the desktop/laptop. Both go directly to the App Store on iOS.

If you'd like to construct the URL yourself, follow my previous instructions:

In iTunes Connect you need to find the "Apple ID" for your app (it's a 9 digit number found in Manage Apps, Ktalu). Then simply find a link to any other app and replace the ID with yours.

For example, the Apple ID for Google Maps is 585027354 and its online URL is https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id585027354.

Comment: I just made a new, unpublished app like yours to see for myself. The link given by "View in App Store" appears to be 100% valid and will link to your game once it goes live. I'm changing my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks - this is indeed what I want. But I'll add an additional idea. If the user is on a non-iOS device, it might be useful to go to the game website rather than just the app store. So I used a redirect script. On the game website ktalu.com I created a PHP script that tests the user-agent for 'iPhone' or 'iPad'. If found it redirects to the app link as you describe above. If not found, then this must be a PC or laptop and we just redirect to ktalu.com. The only downside to this might be more lode on ktalu.com. Anyone see anything else wrong with this?

Comment: Actually, while my above redirect idea will work, I looked at the Google Maps example on my MAC and maybe it is a better idea to just stick with the app store link as you describe. I prefer using https rather than itms because while it makes no diffeence on an iOS device, on a computer the https version loads the description in a browser rather quickly but takes forever to load iTunes directly. But thanks for the quick and useful answer!